# web scraping product and store information from Target

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and looking to pull product data from Target's website.

The highlighted portions of the image

[image]

I have been able to get the product name and price but the rest of the information can't be found using BeautifulSoup. For instance, when inspecting the zip code it shows the zip code with the data-test tag but when searching for the tag it cannot be found. Has anyone experienced this before or know a way to get this information?

Using Python 3 and BeautifulSoup.

Not sure the best way to phrase this question so let me know if you need more information or if I need to rephrase.

```html
<a href="#" class="h-text-underline Link-sc-1khjl8b-0 jvxzGg" data-test="storeFinderZipToggle">35401</a>
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("demofile.txt", "w")

Page_Source = "https://www.target.com/p/nintendo-switch-with-neon-blue-and-neon-red-joy-con/-/A-52189185"

page = requests.get(Page_Source)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#write all the html code to a file to compare source files
f.write(str(soup))

#should contain city location but Secondary header can't be found
#location = soup.find("div", {'class', 'HeaderSecondary'})


#inside the secondary header should contain the store name but is not found
#store_location = location.find('div', {'data-test': 'storeId-store-name'})
#store_location = location.find('button', {'id': 'storeId-utility-NavBtn'})



#contains the rest of the information interested in
main_container = soup.find(id="mainContainer")
#complete_product_name = soup('span',attrs={'data-test':'product-title'})[0].text
product_price = soup.find("span", {'data-test': 'product-price'})
product_title = soup.find("span", {'data-test': 'product-title'})

flexible_fulfillment = main_container.find('div', {'data-test': 'flexible_fulfillment'})

#test = product_zip.find_all('a')
#example = soup.find_all("div", {'data-test': 'storePickUpType'})

example = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'data-test':'maxOrderQuantityTxt'})
print(product_title)
print(product_price)

print(flexible_fulfillment)


f.close()
```

Comment: the store finder is initialized with javascript. you can try using another module like [`selenium`](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/) or [`requests-html`](https://html.python-requests.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Helpful tip using Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


#launch url
url = "https://www.target.com/p/nintendo-switch-with-neon-blue-and-neon-red-joy-con/-/A-52189185"

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get(url)

try:
    store_name_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="storeId-utilityNavBtn"]/div[2]')
    print(store_name_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no store name available"

try:
    item_name_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/span')
    print(item_name_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no item name available"

try:
    price_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/span')
    print(price_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no pricce available"

try:
    zip_code_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a')
    print(zip_code_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no zip code available"

try:
    order_by_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[2]/p')
    print(order_by_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no order by time available"

try:
    arrival_date_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/span')
    print(arrival_date_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no arrival date available"

try:
    shipping_cost_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
    print(shipping_cost_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no shipping cost available"

try:
    current_inventory_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]')
    print(current_inventory_element.get_attribute('innerText'))
except Exception:
    print "There's no current inventory available"

driver.quit()
```

One thing I am noticing with this code though is that it is inconsistent with its results. Sometimes I will get errors saying the element is not found and other times it will find the element. Does anyone know why that may be? is it because I am making frequent requests to the website?

Comment: you could try working with the script tag that contains the info  [type='application/ld+json']  . Also, I'm surprised the site didn't require you to set a location for store but perhaps that is because I am in a different country etc.